# How to alight drawable left near to TextView Android (Or custom snackbar android)

Tags: android, textview, drawable, android-snackbar

I'm using a custom SnackBar for android, I have created SnackBar with an icon and a message. Icon drawable isn't working as expected. The margin text is further than expected. So, this is what I did:
[SnackBar-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM1u6.png)

The expected custom snackbar is: [SnackBar-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2THU.png)
How can I get my expected output? Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
fun showSuccessFullMsg(message: String, anchorView: View) {
    val snackBarView = Snackbar.make(binding.root, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    val view = snackBarView.view
    val params = view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
    snackBarView.setBackgroundTint(resources.getColor(android.R.color.white))
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    val actionBarHeight = anchorView.height

    params.setMargins(32, actionBarHeight.plus(36), 32, 0)
    view.layoutParams = params

    val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)
    textView.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
    val drawable = resources.getDrawable(
        R.drawable.ic_double_check,
        resources.newTheme()
    )
    (textView.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    drawable.bounds = Rect(0, 0, 32, 24)
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)
    textView.isSingleLine = true
    textView.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.END
    view.background =
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            com.proxglobal.ringtone.R.drawable.bg_snackbar
        ) // for custom background
    snackBarView.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
    snackBarView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#23C16B"))
    snackBarView.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
textView.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
```

and programmatically add padding to the start of the *TextView*. You will have to calculate from the sizes of the *TextView*, drawable and text to determine how much padding to apply.

A second way is to add the drawable into the text itself using a [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan).

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me. I used ImageSpan. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for Answer of @Cheticamp.
Finally, Here is my code for this:

```
  @SuppressLint("PrivateResource", "UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
fun showSuccessFullMsg(message: String, anchorView: View) {
    val drawable = resources.getDrawable(
        R.drawable.ic_double_check,
        resources.newTheme()
    )
    drawable.bounds = Rect(0, 0, 64, 48)
    val imageSpan = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)
    val sp = SpannableString("  $message")
    sp.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
    val snackBarView = Snackbar.make(binding.root, sp, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    val view = snackBarView.view
    val params = view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
    snackBarView.setBackgroundTint(resources.getColor(android.R.color.white))
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    val actionBarHeight = anchorView.height

    params.setMargins(32, actionBarHeight.plus(36), 32, 0)
    view.layoutParams = params

    val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)
    textView.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER

    (textView.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    textView.isSingleLine = true
    textView.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.END
    view.background =
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            R.drawable.bg_snackbar
        ) // for custom background
    snackBarView.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
    snackBarView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#23C16B"))
    snackBarView.show()
}
```